# How to exclude classes from component scan based on profiles?

Tags: spring-boot, dependency-injection

The structure of the project is One Web Application consisting of multiple jars (which themselves are mvc apps). The jars are individual projects with their individual `@Configuration` classes which are marked with `@Profile('jarName')` - which scan their respective components. All the jars and the web app have similar package name prefixes.

Eg: `com.foo.bar.webapp.controller` and `com.foo.bar.jar1.controller`

In the main webapp, I was excluding `com.foo.bar.jar1.*` from the component scan using exclude filters. I want to know if there is a way to exclude all components being brought in by a profile ?

Or another way to ask this is, how do I enable component and entity scanning based on active profiles ?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, perhaps a small sample would help. You can use `@ComponentScan` on a `@Configuration` class that also as `@Profile` if that helps. I must say that what you're trying to do does sound very unusual.

Comment: @PhilWebb Is it possible to define values for `@ComponentScan`, `@EntityScan` in a YAML file ? So that when there are more than a handful of modules being brought into a project, in the `Application` class I do not have worry about various scans but simply ask to include all `@ComponentScans` from the active profiles ?  At the moment I am achieving this by creating a `@Configuration` class in each module and annotating it with `@Profile` And by `Import`ing each config class.

Comment: @happybuddha did you find a solution to this? I'm interested to know it